# Unit Test case fails when whole Test Suite is executed

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, unit-testing, xctestcase

I am writing the Unit test cases for my sqlite database class. I have five public API in that class.

My test cases goes something like below:

```
+ (void)setUp {  // Note, this is class method and hence called only once during start of this test suite.
    // Code to delete the existing sqlite DB file.
}

- (void)testDBManagerSingletonInstance {
    DBManager *dbMgr = [DBManager getSharedInstance];
    DBManager *dbMgr1 = [[DBManager alloc] init];
    XCTAssertEqualObjects(dbMgr, dbMgr1);
}

- (void)testSaveAndDeleteNicknameAPI {
    // Multiple Assert statements in this test.
}

- (void)testAllAccountStatusAPIs {
    // Multiple Assert statements in this test.
}
```

Each of the single unit test is executed without any errors. But it fails when whole test suite is executed.

Probably, I know the **Root Cause** for failing. It is because when entire test suite is executed then all test runs in parallel and there is simultaneous update-delete happens in the database. Hence, when all unit tests runs it will fail.

But I don't know how can I fix that, because this is not Async, and hence I cannot use `XCExpectation` class.

Need assistance to resolve & understand the problem.

Comment: You have already stated the answer..If tests are all using the same database then it's contents are all in a state of flux as you say... the solution is to have each unit test look at separate databases or separate instances or separate tables..... or force sequential execution. The rule when testing is you must know the contents of the database .. in this case you never know because it's being setup and tested by multiple processes simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Tests based on `XCTests` don't run in parallel - they are run sequentially. To quote [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/04-writing_tests.html) :

> Tests execute synchronously because each test is invoked independently one after another.

Since you've shown very little code, it's hard to say what is the real problem. It is very likely that you were close with your assumption - you should either improve your `setUp` (maybe switch to instance version from class version) and `tearDown` methods or introduce mocks, and perform your tests on a mocked database if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't work with singletons in a codebase you want to test. I think that your code uses the sharedSingleton instance of DBManager internally. Each unitest will change the internal state of that instance, all following unitests are therefore corrupted. You need to reset all changes after each test case in teardown.

But my suggestion is to avoid singletons in your base code by dependency injection. When creating an instance of your class inject the singleton instance of your DBManager. That makes unit testing easier. If you inject a protocol instead of an object you may even test your code with a protocol fake implementation.